# Set-theoretical subleties in the equivalence between sets over $J$ and functors on $J$

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

In the book *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by Moerdijk and MacLane it says on pages 28 and 29:

> Each such object $h: X \to J$ over J determines a $J$-indexed
> family $\{H_j \mid j \in J\}$ of sets, consisting of the sets
> $$H_j = h^{-1}\{j\} = \{x \mid x \in X\ and\ hx =j\},$$
> and then each arrow $f: h \to h'$ as in (8) determines a $J$-indexed family
> of functions $f_j: H_j \to H_j$, $j \in J$. If we regard the set $J$ here as a
> discrete category ..., then each $J$-indexed family of sets is just a
> functor $H: J \to Sets$ and each $J$-indexed family of functions $f_j$ is just
> a natural transformation $F: H \to H'$ between these functors. In other
> words, the assignments $h \mapsto \{H_j\}$, $f \mapsto \{f_j\}$ constitute a functor
> $$L: Sets/J \to Sets^J,$$
> from the comma category to the functor category.
> Reciprocally, each functor $H: J \to Sets$ determines a set $h: X \to J$
> over $J$, with $X$ the disjoint union (the coproduct) $X = \coprod H_j$ of the sets
> $H_j$ for $j \in J$ and $h$ the function which sends each $x \in X$ into its "index"
> (that $j \in J$ with $x \in H_j$). These two reciprocal constructions amount
> to constructing two functors $L$ and $M$
> $$L: Sets/J \leftrightarrows Sets^J: M$$
> with both $LM$ and $M L$ naturally isomorphic to the respective identity
> functors. Therefore, these two constructions provide an equivalence of
> the comma category $Sets/ J$ to the functor category $Sets^J$. *This equivalence is not an isomorphism of categories because the composite functor
> $M L$ is not the identity, on account of the choice available in the formation of the disjoint union involved in the construction of $M$. (That is,
> many different sets over $J$ correspond under $L $ to the same functor on
> $J$.)*

I don't understand the last, italic, part.

I agree that $ML$ is not equal to the identity (but I also think that $LM$ is not equal to the identity as well, so I don't know why they talk about $ML$).

I don't agree with "(That is,
many different sets over $J$ correspond under $L $ to the same functor on
$J$.)" Firstly, $L$ has nothing to do with taking coproducts, so the text above can't be an explation for that. Also, it's just wrong: $L$ is injective on objects *up to equality*.

(As usual, $\coprod H_j := \{(j, e)\mid j\in J, e\in H_j\}$. Then I also think that a functor on $J$ can be really recovered *up to equality* from its corresponding set over $J$. Hence $M$ is injective on objects up to equality as well.)

Can you confirm that what I write is correct? I would be surprised if MacLane would make such elementary mistakes...

Comment: What is "up to equality"?

Comment: "$L$ is injective on objects up to equality" means the same as "$L$ is injective on objects". But I add "up to equality" to mean that here I'm *not* talking about $L$ being injective on objects only *up to isomorphism*: $LX\cong LY\implies X\cong Y$, which is usually the more sensible condition to discuss.

Comment: I see. I agree that with your definition of the disjoint union it has to be injective. (and with that $LM$ is also not identity) Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that $L$ and $M$ are injective on objects. It seems the point Mac Lane and Moerdijk should have made is that $L$ is not surjective, since functors in the image of $L$ have all their values pairwise disjoint. Incidentally, if one replaces the category of arbitrary functors on $J$ with the image of $L$ (that is, the category of functors with pairwise disjoint values) then one gets a reasonably natural isomorphism of categories replacing the equivalence discussed here by replacing $M$ with the *union*, rather than the disjoint union, of the values. It is not unheard of for Mac Lane to make simple mistakes; you can find at least one more example on this site. But it is indeed not very common.